# How can I send a string to serial /dev/tty.* port, delay a second, disconnect from the port and continue my bash script in OSX?

Tags: macos, bash, serial-port

This is in relation to resetting an Arduino, and then start pushing data to it from my usb xbee.
I've tried using screen, with no luck.

```
screen -S Xbee -d -m /dev/tty.usbserial-A900fra9 115200 *reset
```

I don't know how to close this session, not sure whether the args are correct, either.

Comment: so `echo "myString" > /dev/tty.....` doesn't work? Good luck.

Comment: Probably not if he wants to set a specific baud-rate?

Answer (score 1):

to send anything to devices on /dev, you can use the > >> 2> 2>&1, etc.

Try this example from tty1 (ctrl+alt+F1):

```
echo "my string" > /dev/tty2
```

now go to tty2 (alt+F2) and you gonna see your string. It should work with any device.
and to sleep, use:

```
sleep 1
```

your problem could be also with permissions. Try it with root! ;)